# POST request uploading to Database but not getting custom response

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

So as the title suggest, I am able to send a POST request, and see in my postgresql database (through the pgAdmin client) that the data is being submitted and stored, however I run into a number of errors in the response output. It may have to do with the Authorization, as I have never worked with authorizing before. Both errors produce responses with 500 errors, contrary to what I would like.

The POST request is as follows:

```
def create():
    """
    Create Student Function
    """
    req_data = request.get_json()
    try:
        data = student_schema.load(req_data)
    except ValidationError as err:
        error = err.messages
        return custom_response(error, 400)

    #check if student exists in db
    student_in_db = Student.get_user_by_email(data.get('email'))
    if student_in_db:
        message = {'error': 'Student already exists, please supply another email address'}
        return custom_response(message, 400)
    student = Student(data)
    student.save()

    ser_data = student_schema.dump(student).data
    token = Auth.generate_token(ser_data.get('id'))

    return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 201)
```

The custom_response is as so:

```
def custom_response(res, status_code):
    """
    Custom Response Function
    """
    return Response(
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=json.dumps(res),
        status=status_code
    )
```

**Error 1**
The new entry is stored, however the response to the server is still a 500 error. The error output is an attribute error pointing towards
         `ser_data = student_schema.dump(student).data` 
which is apparently a dict object, thus has no attribute data.

**Error 2**
Emails are declared unique in my database, thus when trying to create another user with the same email, I get a unique constraint failure, which leads to a 500 response, even though I have the built in function of checking if the student is already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

With `flask_sqlalchemy`, I expect to see

```
db.session.add(student)
db.session.commit()
```

unless you're doing that in

```
student.save()
```

Comment: Yes that is what the save function is doing.

Comment: But like I said, the data is being sent and stored to the database, the response From the server is not correct.